# Reloading tableView - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When calling `[self.tableView reloadData];` my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will not run.

**This is what is happening:**

***First Sequence -***

```
- (void)startProcess:(NSInteger)number {
    NSInteger testing = number;
    cellID = testing;
    // MAKE REQuEST TO SERVER
    [self makeRequests];

}
```

***Second sequence -***

```
-(void)makeRequests
{
/* GRAB USERNAME TO BE SENT OVER FOR NOTIFICATIONS */
NSArray *get = [[SSKeychain allAccounts] init];
NSString *username = [get[0] objectForKey:@"acct"];

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"function": @"populateNotfications", @"username" : username};
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (error)
    NSLog(@"%s: JSON encode error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mySite.com/dev/iphone/test.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"json=%@",
                    [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *paramsData = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request addValue:@"8bit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding"];
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[paramsData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:paramsData];


// issue the request
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (error)
    NSLog(@"%s: NSURLConnection error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);

// GRAB STATUS OBJECT
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:returnData //1

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
self.impactsGrabed = [json objectForKey:@"requested_data"];
NSLog(@"grabbing data");
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Now this will cause my `numberOfRowsInSection` to run and work correctly but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` never runs.  Here is my `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.impactsGrabed count];
}
```

`impactsGrabed count` will return for example, 2.

**OUTPUT of tableView:**

`<UITableView: 0x10e00ee00; frame = (0 20; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10c244950>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10c23ffc0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>`

**UPDATE:**

***CELL TABLE CODE:***

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.impactsGrabed count]; <!-- this does return an positive integer.
}

- (double) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 75;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"working cell");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"timelineCell";
    impactTimelineCell *cell = (impactTimelineCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell = [[impactTimelineCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell initTimelineCell];
    cell.statusLabel.text = [self.impactsGrabed[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"message"];
    cell.timestampLabel.text = [self.impactsGrabed[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"time_post"];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // WHEN CLICKING ON A NOTIFICATION FOR THE PAGE

}
```

**Here is what I notice:**

When calling the function `startProcess` from another class that starts the whole process of loading the `tableView cells` it does not work.  If I call the `startProcess` method inside the `viewDidLoad` in that file, on initiation the `tableView cells` do load.

Comment: Check to make sure that self.impactsGrabed is not nil after assigning it to `[json objectForKey:@"requested_data"];` Maybe that key does not exist in the json.

Comment: If you are calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` from another thread, it may not properly refresh the table. Try nesting that call within a dispatch call to the main queue. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [[self.tableView reloadData]; };`

Comment: @micahrosales where exactly would I place the code?

Comment: The same place where you have it now, in the last line of `makeRequests`. Just wrap your current call with the dispatch_async.

Comment: @micahrosales that does not work

Comment: I am assuming you have verified that `self.impactsGrabed` has the proper values before that call, have you added log statements to all of the tableview delegate methods and say explicitly which ones are called?

Comment: No I have'nt but I know everything is correct.

Comment: @micahrosales if I put `    [self makeRequests];
` in the `viewDidLoad` it works fine.  It is only when I call it from that `startProcess` method that it does not.

Comment: when/where is `startProcess` called from?

Comment: Another file on clicking of cell.

Comment: There are a couple things wrong with that model, but neither of them should be the problem here. Firstly, whenever you are doing a data fetch, it should be an asynchronous call, especially if you are waiting for a ui event to happen, such as pushing a new view. You will be blocking the main thread during this time.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know but do you have anyidea what is going on?

Comment: Back to your main problem, have you verified that the function is called from `startprocess`, and fetch and the data returned are executed and have the proper values?

Comment: @micahrosales I have.

Comment: @micahrosales its work because it hits, `numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, heightForRowAtIndexPath` but it wont go to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: can you paste cell tableview methods code..

Comment: cell.statusLabel.text where are you sub viewing "statusLabel" on cell it is not displaying... write this cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor]; in cellforrow and check

Answer (score 1):

cellForRowAtIndexPath won't be called if numberOfRowsInSection returns zero. Just Make sure by debugging your code that numberOfRowsInSection is returning nonzero value.

Comment: It is returning a valid integer.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, no need to reload since you are not doing the request asynchronously

```
//[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Make sure you return at least one section

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This still does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `self.tableView` 's `delegate` and `dataSource` are not properly connected.

Comment: I don't think I am setting them.

Comment: You need to set them to make tableView's delegate methods get called.

Comment: They are set automatically if you are using a UITableViewController

Comment: @drewag that is what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after some wonderful help from `Mr.rdelmar`. This was the issue:

So because I was calling the code from a child `container` of a `ViewController` I had to initiate the following in my `startProcess`:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSInteger tag = cell.tag;
        impact* myScript = self.parentViewController.childViewControllers[1]; // if my script is one of the child view controllers, then this is how you need to access it -- the number might be 0,1 or 2 depending on which one is the impact controller
        [myScript startProcess:tag];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Happy Coding!